# Android Aapt2InternalException in compilation

Tags: android, command-line, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

Android sdk installation steps:

```
wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip -O android-sdk-tools.zip \
 && unzip -q android-sdk-tools.zip -d ${ANDROID_HOME} \
 && rm android-sdk-tools.zip
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

Clone an android project from github. clean task works fine.

```
$git clone and-repo-url
$cd and-repo && ./gradlew clean
```

There is no platform and build-tools yet.

```
$ls /opt/android-sdk-linux
licenses  tools
```

Building apk is failed:

```
$./gradlew  :app:assembleDebug
```

This task installs build-tools and platforms

```
$ls /opt/android-sdk-linux
build-tools     licenses        platform-tools  platforms       tools

$ls /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/28.0.2/
NOTICE.txt                  arm-linux-androideabi-ld    i686-linux-android-ld       mainDexClassesNoAapt.rules  split-select
aapt                        bcc_compat                  lib                         mipsel-linux-android-ld     x86_64-linux-android-ld
aapt2                       core-lambda-stubs.jar       lib64                       package.xml                 zipalign
aarch64-linux-android-ld    d8                          llvm-rs-cc                  renderscript
aidl                        dexdump                     mainDexClasses              runtime.properties
apksigner                   dx                          mainDexClasses.rules        source.properties
```

Error message is here:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Comment: run this command './gradlew --no-daemon assembleDebug'

Comment: @RanjanKumar same issue :/ 
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Comment: Check if gradle.properties file has 'org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m'

Comment: @RanjanKumar The app builds on mac or some linux machines. I think sdk or jdk is missing

Answer (score 0):

I had installed android sdk on linux machine by following steps.
Download android sdk from link 'https://developer.android.com/studio' from section 'Command line tools only'.

sdkmanager is located in android_sdk/tools/bin/. use sdkmanager to download other packages. create a package name 'SDK_26'

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.3"
sdkmanager "platforms;android-26"
sdkmanager "platform-tools"
sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
```

[download linux 64-bit ndk from location 'https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/' and rename it to 'ndk-bundle'

And compile the app as

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/desktop/android/SDK_26
export JAVA_HOME=/sw/licensed/sun/jdk/1.8.0_91
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
chmod 777 gradlew
./gradlew
./gradlew assembleRelease
```