# How to fix 'Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2' error when build a android project by gradle build step on TeamCity?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, teamcity

I've installed TeamCity 2019.1 in my PC to test CI/CD on Android projects. But I'm facing the following problem when build the project only in TeamCity:

```
[10:23:22]  [Step 1/3] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
[10:23:24]  [Step 1/3] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
```

This question is similar to my problem but that case the error occurs in Android Studio: [question]: [Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' Error on creating first project on windows android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56620362/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-error-on-creating-first-pro)

In Android Studio that project works fine. I tried to checkout this project from Github and build it running `gradlew clean build` and it also works fine for me.

*Following the build log:*

```
[10:23:24]  [Step 1/3] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
[10:23:23]  [Step 1/3] 
[10:23:23]  [Step 1/3] 10 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 1 up-to-date
[10:23:24]  [Step 1/3] Process exited with code 1
[10:23:24]  [Step 1/3] Gradle failure report
[10:23:24]  [Step 1/3] Process exited with code 1 (Step: gradle-build (Gradle))
[10:23:24]  [Step 1/3] Step gradle-build (Gradle) failed
```

Any guess about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have a similar issue on TC 2017.

Comment: Also, your Stack Overflow link is dead.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @TalShani unfortunately not.

Comment: @JonathanGiorgiSilveira so what did end up doing? how did you build your app using team city?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

- Ctrl+Alt+Suppr to open task manager
- Kill all "Java(TM) Platform SE binary" process
- react-native run-android

Answer (score -1):

You need to give path of SDK installed on the build machine.

Check the answer from this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56421370/4181904

Comment: But the system knows where the SDK is installed. How else would it be attempting to build?

Comment: system will search at default location. If your SDK is not at default location, then you need to tell this to gradle build system.

Comment: Your link is to a solution related to Linux. This is for a Windows TeamCity build agent. What is the "default location"? Again, I don't see how it would even be getting to AAPT2 if gradle can't find the Android SDK.